# Appending Windows Directories In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program that appends audio files the user selects together using Sox.

I originally created the program for linux but I am making it compatible with Windows. On windows when I pass the list of files to Sox, the program raises 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.'

When I print out the list of files it is `C:\\\MyProgram\\\` And So On. How Do I Make The `'\\'` in the path become `'\'`?

I'm on windows 8.1, so that may be the problem.

I have tried:

```
str(nameoffile)

os.path.abspath(nameoffile)

os.path.normpath(nameoffile)
```

There is a huge list of files and directories, so setting the absolute file of each is not an option, I am using os.path.join() to allow the user to navigate through the folders.

But when I pass the files into the list and then call the list using `subprocess.list2cmdline(mylist)`, it simply raises that error above.

Example:

```
mydirectory = os.getcwd()

appendlist = list()

appendlist.append("sox")

for x, i in enumerate(self.fileselected): # A List Of Files The User Selected

    directory = chosendirectory

    nextfile = os.path.join(chosendirectory, i)

    appendlist.append(nextfile)

subprocess.call([subprocess.list2cmdline(appendlist)], shell=True)
```

When `os.path.join` appends the files....it produces "`C:\\\Program\\\file`" and then it is converted to `str()`. The str() reads "`C:\\\Program\\\file`" and the escape character does not register in a string. How do I remove the escape character to pass it into the list as valid windows directory?

Comment: [this](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/os_module.html) tutorial might help you. Working with paths in Windows is a PITA because ``\`` is the escape character for strings in just about every language in the history of time. The TL;DR, in string literals the path delimiter is always going to be ``'\\'`` because that's how you get a regular ``r'\'`` out of a string.

Comment: that was helpful, however for whatever reason subprocess doesn't like '\\' it still raises the error even when iterating. Is there a built in method in the os module or elsewhere to make the '\\' into '\' on a string or a list?

Comment: Check out [this](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/). My guess is that doing ``os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(nameoffile))`` will get the job done.

Comment: still no but thanks for the help. I am passing the filenames into subprocess as string literals. Is there a method to take 'C:\\Programs\\' and make the '\\' >> '\'? String formatting is not my expertise.

Comment: put a small sample of the code above. It isn't properly indented but it should suffice. Subprocess raises 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.' when it is called.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. How would I do this with the subprocess.Popen method instead of subprocess.call

Comment: Yes. sox Is In PATH. I tested it in command prompt and in the pycharm terminal and it found sox. How do I remove the 2 slashes (\\) and convert them to one (\) for each item in that list.

Comment: where sox >> C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-1\sox.exe

Comment: maybe I didn't specify the question properly. And thanks for all your guy's help. Python has no problem finding sox. It doesn't recognize "C:\\Program\\File" as a valid file because there are 2 backslashes (\\\) and windows doesn't like that apparently. I want to know how to remove one of those backslashes so sox can recognize the string as a valid identifier to the list of files I am trying to concatenate

Comment: sure enough. I iterated each item through a for loop and there is only 1 backslash. Why windows didn't just put a forward slash like the rest of the programming world I have no idea. Is there a better way to pass in the list to subprocess? The way I have listed is the only way I have found I can make it work.

Comment: SOLVED. Thanks for your guy's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the call if you change the current working directory for the subprocess:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(['sox'] + self.fileselected, cwd=chosendirectory)
```

Note: you don't need `shell=True` unless you want to run an internal (shell builtin) command such as `start`.

---

Backslashes has special meaning inside Python string *literals* in the source code.

```
>>> len('\\') == 1 # a single backslash inside the string
True
```

Backslashes has no special meaning in a string object (in memory) i.e., you shouldn't care about backslashes unless you manually write the paths in your Python source code -- if you read the path from a file; you don't need to escape them. If you read the paths from a GUI; you don't need to escape them. If you read the paths from the output of a subprocess; you don't need to escape them, etc.

If you print `repr(path)`; it shows you how Python string literal would look like i.e., the backslashes are doubled (escaped). If you print: `[path]` then it is equivalent to `'['+repr(path)+']'`. If you print the string along `print(path)` then `repr` is not called on the string object and the backslashes are not doubled.

For Windows paths and regex patterns, you could use raw-string  literal where backslashes are not escaped e.g., `r'C:\Path\n\f' == 'C:\\Path\\n\\f'` (notice: `r` prefix).